# DI - How to refactor constructor with lots of dependencies

Tags: php, oop

I'm fairly new to dependency injection, and I've come upon a situation where I have a class which is basically just functional programming -- one method in it (`createPayment`) requires 9 dependencies, and the other method (`paypalApiEndpoint`) only requires 1 of those dependencies:

```
class Paypal
{
    private $restAPIClient;
    private $db;
    private $logger;
    private $paypalGateway;
    private $paymentGateway;
    private $ordersGateway;
    private $usersGateway;
    private $resourcesGateway;
    private $configGateway;

    public function __constructor($restAPIClient, $db, $logger, // ...6 more, each for the private vars) 
    {
        $this->restAPIClient = $restAPIClient;
        $this->db= $db;
        $this->logger= $logger;
        // ... 6 more
    }

    // this method uses all 9 dependencies from the constructor
    public function createPaypalPayment()
    {
        // insert purchase info into `payment` db table. Requires $paymentGateway and $db

        // make paypal API call. Requires $restAPIClient, $db, $paypalGateway, $logger

        // based on API call results, update `orders`, `users`, `payment`, `resources`, and `config` db tables. Requires $db, $logger, $paymentGateway, $ordersGateway, $usersGateway, $resourcesGateway, $configGateway
    }

    // this method only requires 1 of the dependencies, $paypalGateway
    public function paypalApiEndpoint()
    {
        // get a value from our db table `paypal`, and return it. Requires $paypalGateway
    }
}
```

In many places throughout my codebase I *only* need to use the `paypalApiEndpoint` method. The problem is, in order to use that method I have to first create 9 objects (the dependencies of class Paypal), then I can use those to create the Paypal object, and then finally I can use the simple `paypalApiEndpoint` method. Needing to create 10 objects in order to this very simple method seems overboard.

Is there a better way?

Comment: This is a contrived example, but it is basically what I am doing now. I have some interactions with Paypal so I thought putting all of those into one single class would be a good idea. Moving the `paypalApiEndpoint` to a new class itself did not seem like a good idea. I also thought of, and have in the past, made the dependencies method dependencies (passed all the dependencies directly to the `createPaypalPayment` method). But that creates more complications down the road...the class Paypal can be constructed without "everything it needs to work" properly. Thanks for your time.

Comment: It does seem like a code smell, but the things you're leaving out, both the 6 other dependencies plus your method implementation, are the things that can give conclusive insight into your actual design problem.

Comment: @GerardvanHelden thanks I have updated both of those to fully explain (hopefully). I left off those details thinking it would simplify the question.

Comment: @PedroAmaralCouto it requires one of the dependencies that is in the constructor, $paypalGateway

Comment: There is no better way, without rethinking the design. You can ask yourself, are these DB operations applicable only for PayPal payments? If they are not, they should not be in the class named Paypal. If you add another payment method you won't be able to reuse this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// this method only requires 1 of the dependencies, $paypalGateway
public function paypalApiEndpoint()
{
    // get a value from our db table `paypal`, and return it. Requires $paypalGateway
}
```

If the only requirement is the `paypalGateway`, then move the implementation to the `paypalGateway` class or an extension.

That doesn't mean you would have to remove the method from the `Paypal` class:

```
public function paypalApiEndpoint()
{
    return $this->paypalGateway->paypalApiEndpoint();
}
```

Further, your constructor has lots of parameters.
I believe it would be better to have a Builder class with all the dependencies, using setters, that would be injected as an argument:

https://jlordiales.me/2012/12/13/the-builder-pattern-in-practice/

Or implement composites of related data reducing the parameters number:

https://refactoring.guru/smells/data-clumps

Taking into account that the `Paypal` constructor has lots of parameters: 
https://refactoring.guru/smells/long-parameter-list

> If there are several unrelated data elements, sometimes you can merge
>   them into a single parameter object via Introduce Parameter Object.

https://refactoring.guru/introduce-parameter-object

- > By consolidating parameters in a single class, you can also move the
  >   methods for handling this data there as well, freeing the other
  >   methods from this code.
- > (...) see whether there is any point in moving a part of the method
  >   (or sometimes even the whole method) to a parameter object class. If
  >   so, use Move Method or Extract Method.

This means that if you only need to invoke `paypalApiEndpoint`, you may use only the `paypalGateway` class for your purposes, with less dependancies than the `Paypal` class.

Comment: This is a really good answer! I'd like to go any further: why does your class need to do database stuff **and** API calls in one big thing? Break that up into one more class to do the database stuff and one more class for the API bindings, call them both from the existing class and your setup will look much better than today

Comment: Thanks, @NicoHaase. I'm not sure what is exactly - for instance - the $db, but if it's a generic object to access a database, I agree with you. It should be a "respository" or a "storage" specifically for Paypal related data. You should be able to easily use the $restAPIClient class without using the $db class, and vice-versa. The Paypal class should be an handy way to call both because that's a common use case, otherwise you have the same problem with $paypalGateway.

Comment: "The Paypal class should be an handy way to call both because that's a common use case"  Yes this is the use case. Step 1 insert payment info (item #, purchase price, etc into a paypal db table), Step 2 generate a paypal payment

Comment: @KayakinKoder, the trick is to always implement specialized logic inside the specialized collaborators and the manager single responsibility should be to delegate the job to the collaborators (ie: manage, like the controller in MVC). When you need work from a collaborator without that manager, the solution will become obvious and easier without changing the manager.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to inject all your dependencies in the constructor.  You can have setter injectors for optional parameters.

```
public function setRestAPIClient($restAPIClient) {
    $this->restAPIClient = $restAPIClient;
};
```

In your example, paypalApiEndpoint is a good candidate to be turned into either a class constant and/or a static method that would then allow you to use it via:

```
class PayPal {
    private static $paypalGateway = null;

    public static setPaypalGateway($paypalGateway) {
       self::paypalGateway = $paypalGateway;
    }

    public __construct(.... all params) {
       self::paypalGateway = $paypalGateway;
       $this->otherDependency = $otherDependency;
    }                
}
```

For static use you just have to call the static setter 1 time, then use as much as you want within script execution.

```
Paypal::setPaypalGateway($ppgateway);
$endpoint = Paypal::paypalApiEndpoint();
```

Last but not least, you might want to look into use of a DI Container Component.

Some DIC's now feature autowiring which can determine what they need to load at calltime using typehints.

There is a standard [PSR standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-11/) for how DI Containers should work and [Symfony2's DIC](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html), Laravel's DIC and PHP-DI for example, all conform to those standards and can easily be used to handle class loading within your application.

As mentioned, [PHP-DI](http://php-di.org/) is another DIC component you might want to look at as well.

Comment: Thanks, yes I'm getting around to DI Container but am not quite to understanding that yet. I edited my question so that comments in `createPaypalPayment` hopefully make it clear "why" I need all of these dependencies; would you really use setter injectors in this example? I guess assuming that `paypalApiEndpoint` was a bit more complicated and it itself required maybe one of the dependencies.

Comment: With your limited example, I'd use a static method given your statement that when you create a new instance for use with createPayPalPayment, you need all the dependencies.  It seems that your other concern is with performance, and that is where a Container helps you out, sometimes with the aid of either a Service Locator that supports lazy loading, or an addon proxy library in more general situations where you have a number of dependencies.

Comment: Just want to comment here that long after I answered, the question code was changed undercutting my point, but I still think this could be handled somewhat elegantly with a static variable.

Comment: yes it was, thanks though for your answer. Particularly DI Container is something we need to implement